What is the fastest way to get money in Anno 1800?
Of course the fastest way to gain money in Anno 1800 is to get a lot of investors. But I wanted to know if there are other fast ways to generate a lot of money exept of building a lot of houses for people and satisfy their needs. Thank you for your help!

A good way to get a lot of money in a very short time is to buy gramophones from Archibald Blake and sell them to Ketema. Blake sells gramophones for 27506 money per ton and Ketema buys them for 44009 money per ton. So you will get 16503 money for each ton of gramophones you transport from the Old World to Enbesa. The problem is you need a lot of money to buy the gramophones first but its definitely worth it. Its also a good way to earn a lot of money in early- and middlegame.
